# How to use Postgres array "contains" condition with Hibernate?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I wrote a Postgres query as below and it is failing at build. How to implement it in Spring-boot Hibernate?

```
 @Query(value="SELECT t from CatalogView t WHERE t.locations=:locations AND STRING_TO_ARRAY(t.myColumn, ',') @> STRING_TO_ARRAY(:myColumn, ',')")
 public Set<TrainerGuides> getData(@Param("locations") String locations,@Param("myColumn") String myColumn);
```

**Why i wrote this?**
to compare a bunch of strings separated by coma with unorder string input in Postgres.

```
    catalog
    ----------------------------------
    id   title     keywords
    ----------------------------------
    1    Title-1   k2,k1,k3,k4,k5
    2    Title-2   k1,k3,k5,k6
```

To select the rows by comparing keywords with my input k1,k2,k5

In this above example, row with id: 1 has to come.

```
SELECT *
FROM   catalog
WHERE  STRING_TO_ARRAY(keywords, ',') @> STRING_TO_ARRAY('k1,k2,k5', ',')
```

Comment: Identifier names such as tables, columns, functions cannot be inserted using parameters. It is a security precaution.

Comment: Does `@Query` indicate a native query? You won't be able to use DBMS specific functions and operators in HQL or JPQL

Comment: you have to set nativeQuery=true inside @Query()

Comment: @DHARMENDRASINGH I am able to build it. I hope expected results will come now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can extend Hibernate Postgresql Dialect and add native database functions to your HQL here is the example :

I've never used STRING_TO_ARRAY but the rest works fine.

```
public class PostgreSQLDialect extends org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
{

public PostgreSQLDialect()
{
    super();
    registerFunction("replace", new StandardSQLFunction("replace", Hibernate.STRING));
    registerHibernateType(Types.ARRAY, "array"); 
    registerFunction( "string_agg", new StandardSQLFunction("string_agg", Hibernate.STRING) );
    registerFunction( "generate_series", new StandardSQLFunction("generate_series") );
    registerFunction( "STRING_TO_ARRAY", new StandardSQLFunction("STRING_TO_ARRAY", Hibernate.STRING) );
}

@Override
public boolean supportsTupleDistinctCounts()
{
    return true;
}

}
```